# How to get id and value for a dropdown menu from another table in php

Tags: drop-down-menu, get

I have two tables. "cat" & "image".

Database name is "phpimage".

'cat' table has two columns. "id" and "name".

I want to get 'id' and 'name' from 'cat' table for a drop down list

```
<select>
    <option value="THIS SHOULD BE id">THIS SHOULD BE name</option>
</select>
```

And the image table has three column. "imgid" , "catid" and "title".

And I want to store that selected 'id' from the 'cat' table to 'catid' in the 'image' table.

PLEASE HELP ME....

PHP:

```
<?php
include "conn.php";

mysql_select_db($database_phpimage,$phpimage);

$qur="SELECT * FROM cat";
$res=mysql_query($qur,$phpimage);

$cat_name = $_GET['name'];
$cat_id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
    <select name="image_upload">
        <option value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">
            <?php echo $cat_name; ?>
        </option>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What database server are you using? What database library are you using? What have you tried so far to achieve this? StackOverflow is a service for helping you when you have a specific problem, not a code-writing service.

Comment: I am using php and mysql. XAMPP version 5.6.0.0
Following code is the code that i tried.
But there is NULL value list.. I want to get 'name' values and 'id'.
CAN YOU HELP ME ??? 

<?php
 include "conn.php";
 
 mysql_select_db($database_phpimage,$phpimage);
 $qur="SELECT * FROM cat";
 $res=mysql_query($qur,$phpimage);
 
 $cat_name = $_GET['name'];
 $cat_id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<html>
<body>
 <?php 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {  
?>
  <select name="image_upload">
   <option value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></option>
  </select>
 <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: CAN ANYBODY HELP ME ???????

Comment: Please don't shout! Your question is kind of hard to understand. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is happening instead? What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: :) I explained my question clearly :) 
Anyway thank you for the responding oxguy3 :) 
I will try it another solution .... :) Thanks :)

Comment: I couldn't really understand. Was your issue that the id and name were not printing out correctly? Was the issue that you didn't know how to store the data from one table in another? I don't understand what you wanted to do that you weren't able to do, and I don't understand what was happening instead of the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution. Anyway Thanks Stack Overflow.
Here is the code I found.

```
<?php
include "conn.php";
error_reporting(0);
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
    mysql_select_db($database_phpimage,$phpimage);
    $qur="SELECT id,name FROM cat";
    $res=mysql_query($qur,$phpimage);
?>
    <select name="image_upload">
        <option id="0">-- Select an Option --</option>

        <?php
            $getData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat");

            while($viewData = mysql_fetch_array($getData)) 
            { ?>
                <option id="<?php echo $viewData['id']; ?>"><?php echo $viewData['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        ?>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the code I needed. Thanks.